# Check if the content of a DIV is empty in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, size

How do I use jQuery to check to see if the content of a `<div>` is empty?

I tried this and is doesn't seem to be printing the correct values.

```
...
var unframed_items = $("#unframed-items");
alert(unframed_items.html().length);
...
<div id="unframed-items"> </div>
...
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you mean really empty, use the [`empty-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) :

```
alert( !!$("#unframed-items:empty").length )
```

or

```
alert( $("#unframed-items").is(':empty') )
```

If you consider whitespace-only to be empty, then use the [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method:

```
alert( !$.trim( $("#unframed-items").html() ) );
```

Comment: @Jason: Just to give a boolean result in the alert. Could also do a comparison to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="portfolio"><!--portfolio-->
<div id="portfolio-works"><!--portfolio-works-->
    <div class="portfolio-works-container"></div>
</div><!--/portfolio-works-->
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('div.portfolio-works-container').is(':empty')){
        $('div#portfolio').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('#elementId').is(':empty')`.