# how to check if a div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a div that has some content inside of it but when its empty I want it to say something like div is empty

heres my code

```
<div class="results">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Just a simple google search yielded me this   http://html-tuts.com/check-if-div-is-empty-html-element-has-children-tags/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the content of a DIV is empty in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419682/check-if-the-content-of-a-div-is-empty-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

CSS has a pseudo class `:empty` exactly for this purpose. Use that to find the right `div`s, and use CSS pseudo element `::before` to insert the text you want to display in empty divs:

```css
.results:empty::before {
  content: "I feel so empty";
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">Hello</div>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the text content of `<div>` by `.text()`, use `trim()` to remove spaces.

```js
var isEmpty = $('.results').text().trim() === '';
console.log( isEmpty );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *jquery* like this:

```
if ($('.results').is(':empty')){
  // insert code here
}
```

Edit: `#div` is a placeholder.

Edit 2: Changed `#div` to `.results`

```js
if ($('.results').is(':empty')){
  console.log('empty');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">Hello</div>
<div class="results"></div>
<div class="results">World</div>
```

Comment: OP's code does not have an element with the `id` `div`.

Comment: OP might have many divs on the same page. All have `.results`, but none has an `id`. And now? Added that case as a snippet to your answer. Please check to understand the problem of your approach.

Comment: @connexo Thank you, I'll improve on my answering in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own. You can get all the contents of a div with `$.html()`, so check

```
if $("myDiv").html() == ""
```

and this is your answer.

You can make it as a standalone function

```
function isDivEmpty(elementId){
    return $(elementId).html() == "";
}
```

or extend jQuery to have access to it anywhere.

```
$.fn.isEmpty = function(){
    return $(this).html() == "";
}
// usage
alert($("#test").isEmpty()); // alerts true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain javascript

```
 var isEmpty = document.getElementsByClassName('results').innerHTML === "";
```

using jquery

```
 var isEmpty = $(".results").html() === "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to check if a `div` is empty:

```js
var isEmpty = !$(".results")[0].hasChildNodes();
console.log(isEmpty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">Bello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can find the working solution here
https://jsfiddle.net/06nLec5t/8/

used id to identify the empty `div` name, or you can exclude that.

Comment: the one who marked the answer down, please mark the concern for marking it down, Hope it will help my answering skills in future.